# How to handle data over time without a date column?

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop, data-transform

I have a dataset which has many columns listing multiple years worth of values, example:

| Country | 2020 Rank X | 2020 Rank Y | 2021 Rank X |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EU | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| USA | 2 | 3 | 4 |

Etc. Each year has about 6 values for each country and there is 4 years of data, approx 160 rows.

My problem is when attempting to display over time data, there is no functioning "year" column or any data Power BI recognises as a date. How do i convert from the year info in the column name to use-able/able to be filtered year information?

Comment: As Umut answered, you need to unpivot your data to generate data in the appropriate format. Once you are done with your unpivoting, you can create your own Date and other columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should unpivot and pivot again on the Power Query side. then you can use `DATE(<year>, <month>, <day>)`  on the powerbi side...

try :

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45Wcg1VUNJRMgQRRiDCWClWJ1opNNgRIQIiTJRiYwE=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Country = _t, #"2020 Rank X" = _t, #"2020 Rank Y" = _t, #"2021 Rank X" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Country", type text}, {"2020 Rank X", Int64.Type}, {"2020 Rank Y", Int64.Type}, {"2021 Rank X", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Country"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Year", each Text.Start([Attribute],4)),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom",{{"Year", type date}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Changed Type1", List.Distinct(#"Changed Type1"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

Comment: Thank you! I realise now I did not understand what the unpivot/pivot functions were and how they applied to my issue. I did struggle to use your code unfortunately, just because I had so many column names to include. but using the standard unpivot other columns selection and pivot worked fine.